# How to update the existing User SignInName using Azure AD Graph API or Microsft Graph API?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

How can I update the SignInName of an existing user in Azure AD using Microsoft Graph or Azure AD Graph Client.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it won't be possible to update SignInName through either Microsoft Graph API or Azure Graph API. It may be worth a try using PowerShell if that fits your use case (again this may or may not work). Details about each one below..

1. **Update User SignInName using Microsoft Graph API**

   This isn't possible because SignInNames collection isn't even
   available as part of the user entity in Microsoft Graph yet.

   Here is a GitHub issue thread on this topic, look towards the end.
   [Add signInNames property to User. #91](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/91)

[image]

2. **Update User SignInName using Azure AD Graph API**

You would be able to set the User SignInNames collection only at the time of creation of user. See the documentation mentions only POST and GET (no PATCH)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity

[image]

[image]

3. **Update User SignInName using PowerShell**

   This may work out, but I'm not sure about it. Then again, you asked specifically for Microsoft Graph or Azure AD Graph API so your scenario may not be suited for PowerShell.

   [Set-AzureADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0)

[image]

Comment: I want to update the signInName of the user not the userprincipalName.
I tried to update the signInName but in Active Directory client its a read only property , whereas in Microsoft Graph client, the property itself is missing

Comment: @prateek I've updated the answer, please take a look.

Comment: I am not able to update the signInName using powershell. COuld you please share a sample if you have.

Answer (score 1):

You can PATCH the `signInNames` using the Azure AD Graph API (`graph.windows.net`) as an update.

```
PATCH https://graph.windows.net/{tenantId}/users/{userId}?api-version=1.6
Content-Type: application/json

BODY:
{
    "givenName": "James Wood",
    "signInNames": [
        {
            "type": "userName",
            "value": "jamesWoodUserName"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just use GraphBeta sdk.

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet

```
> Install-Package Microsoft.Graph.Beta

var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The email is then under "Identities"

[debug-watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60QJH.png)